# Parameter 'angle' hides field 'float Utils.Transform.float'

Tags: c#

I an relatively new to C#, having a little trouble understanding this message and how it is causing problems. The error was not showing up before I installed resharper, so I presume it is just sugar syntax error?

```
public void SetTransform(float x, float y, float angle)
{
    SetTransform(x, y);
    this.angle = angle;
}
```

And the field itself:

```
float angle;
```

I am confused, how can the parameter in the method be hiding a field variable?...

Comment: A suggestion about Resharper: remove the warnings you are not interested in. Having all the code unnecessarily underlined makes you skip the real warnings.

Comment: One step ahead. lol.

Answer (score 7):

This is a warning telling you that you may confuse those two variables:

```
class IDontKnow
{
    float angle;

    public void SetTransform(float x, float y, float angle) {
        SetTransform(x, y);
        this.angle = angle; // Its not really clear by the naked eye which angle is used.
    }
}
```

I suggest renaming the field angle by using an underscore like so:

```
class IDontKnow
{
    float _angle;

    public void SetTransform(float x, float y, float angle) {
        SetTransform(x, y);
        _angle = angle; // using underscore as a prefix makes the use of this-keyword redundant.
    }
}
```

In general you need some "clear" naming conventions with clean distinction for (protected and higher scoped) fields and properties, method parameters and local variables. This makes code more readable and avoids the mentioned warning.

Comment: Yeah I thought this as much, I actually asked below if _angle would be the correct or rather conventional way of doing it. I come from a Java background and never had this problem, I've always known that this.whatever is referring to the class. Unless in C# this is used some other way?

Comment: Just like in java there are namingconventions. Look them up, find your favourite way and stick to it. (people tend to say underscore is a nono but thats some religious topic)

Comment: StyleCop defaults to always using `this` for accessing any class member though. It was unusual for me and in the beginning it was hard to break old habits. But, I've started to appreciate that it gives a clear distinction of when you are using class methods and when you are calling external methods. For the private fields the _ prefix does the same job. In general I really like the StyleCop conventions. The only issue is that I tend to have problems choosing a good name for the params in the constructor - to avoid the potential issue that R# warns about.

Answer (score 4):

Seems pretty clear - you have a parameter named `angle` that is hiding the class field (`this.angle`)

It's not causing any problems, but if you had existing code that referenced the field directly (instead of using `this.`, then it would be using the parameter value instead.

The reason it started showing up with Resharper is because Resharper does a better job of warning about such cases; it's not invalid code so it's not a compiler error.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating further, I understand how field hiding works but never knew that a parameter could hide a field, I always thought the parameter was only local to the method itself, which it is. So how exactly is this avoided? Using _angle for the member field instead?

Comment: It's not "hiding" in the same sense that you can "hide" an inherited member with `new`, but it's the same concept.  How you avoid it is by naming properties with a capital letter and fields with an underscore.

Comment: Or just stick with what you have; it's not an _error_, resharper is just warning you that `angle` has two different meanings in that context.  If you use `this.` to access the field then you are fine.

Comment: Why does Resharper complain about this when you do it in a method call, but not if you do it in a constructor?